# Spherical to Cartesian Coordinate Converter

Tags: python

I am simply trying to create a working spherical to Cartesian coordinate converter. However, it is not producing the correct solutions and I have multi-checked that the equations for conversion are correct. Even more odd is that this function works in another script, but not on its own. I am using Spyder. Why is this happening?

```
import numpy as np

R = 0.02
Phi = 90
Theta = 0

def Sphere2Cart(r,theta,phi):
    xOut = r*np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta)
    yOut = r*np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta)
    zOut = r*np.cos(phi)
    return xOut,yOut,zOut

x,y,z = Sphere2Cart(R,Theta,Phi)
```

The answer it gives me:

[image: Answer the definition provides]

The correct answer should be: (x,y,z) = (0.02,0,0)

Comment: What packages are you using, and which versions? Also, please don’t share the output as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `R`, `Phi` and `Theta` are in degrees, but numpy [uses radians](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html) for trigonometric functions.

To convert the values to radians, use `np.deg2rad()` (or `math.radians()`):

```
x,y,z = Sphere2Cart(R, np.deg2rad(Theta), np.deg2rad(Phi))
```

Comment: Besides the fact that the function does not need to be applied to "r", the rest worked. Thank you!